# Синтаксическая ошибка при запросе INSERT

Tags: mysql

Появилась ошибка:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax;
>   check the manual that corresponds to
>   your MySQL server version for the
>   right syntax to use near 'order
>   (title, price, total_price, f_name,
>   s_name, o_name, phone, adress, time,
>   d' at line 1

Данная ошибка появилась при попытке вставить таблицы в базу:

```
if($_SESSION['cart'] && isset($_POST['orders'])){

    foreach($_POST as $ArrKey => $ArrKey)
    {
        $ArrKey = $_POST[$ArrKey];
    }
    //$date = date('Y-m-d');
    //$time = date('H:i:s');

    foreach($_SESSION['cart'] as $id => $qty):
        $product = find_product($id);
        $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO order (title, price, total_price, f_name, s_name, o_name, phone, adress, time, date, pr_id) VALUES ('{$product['title']}','{$product['price']}','{$product['total_price']}','$f_name','$s_name','$o_name','$phone','$adress','$time','$date','{$product['id']}')") or die (mysql_error());
    endforeach;
}
```

Comment: @gunaevart, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 1):

Почему-то кажется, что order как зарезервированое слово разбирает.
Попробуте его в кавычки обратные взять:

```
INSERT INTO `order` (title ...
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное, так всё заработало: `order`

Comment: парсер съел кавычки, но они подразумеваются =)